# Trigger preventing a column from being updated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a trigger as below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertUpdateATLastViewedMatch
     ON  dbo.AT_LastViewedMatch
     FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- update statements for trigger here

    declare @id1 int, @matchFK int;

    select @id1 = i.id from inserted i;
    select @matchFK=i.AT_MatchFk from inserted i;
    update dbo.AT_LastViewedMatch set matchId = @matchFK where id = @id1;

END
GO
```

While this trigger works- I am not able to update the value of the matchId column directly from SQLManager:

If I execute

```
UPDATE AT_LastViewedMatch set matchId='1179619' where id=5762
```

for example, I am still seeing the old value for matchId. I think the issue is related to the above trigger (since if I drop the trigger, it works). Is there a way to get past this?

Comment: Do you want to be able to update the value or not? You can't run a trigger *only* when SSMS is the client..

Comment: Your **main flaw** is that you seem to assume the trigger is called **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case with SQL Server. If your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` affects multiple rows, the trigger will be called **once per statement**, and the pseudo tables `Inserted` and `Deleted` can contain multiple rows. So which of these rows are you selecting when doing `select @id1 = i.id from inserted i;` ??? It's not defined - you get **one, arbitrary** row and all other are ignored.... you need to re-write your trigger to handle **multiple rows** in `Inserted` and `Deleted` !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fixed the trigger to account for multiple rows being updated.
 Effectively, I just want the trigger to fire when I update AT_matchFk column and not matchId column. 
 At the same time, I would like to update matchId column independent of AT_matchFk column (I don't want the trigger to fire then). Is this possible

Answer (score 0):

From your trigger definition below, you have created it for `insert and update`

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertUpdateATLastViewedMatch
     ON  dbo.AT_LastViewedMatch
     FOR INSERT,UPDATE <-- Here
```

so essentially, whenever you are running an update statement from SSMS

```
UPDATE AT_LastViewedMatch set matchId='1179619' where id=5762
```

Your trigger performing the below line and setting it to old value

```
update dbo.AT_LastViewedMatch set matchId = @matchFK where id = @id1;
```

You need to remove that `update` from your trigger definition

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertUpdateATLastViewedMatch
     ON  dbo.AT_LastViewedMatch
     FOR INSERT
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First, I changed my trigger as below to account for the trigger to be called multiple timesCREATE TRIGGER InsertUpdateATLastViewedMatchBulk
  ON  dbo.AT_LastViewedMatch
  FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
   
   update AT_LastViewedMatch
   set matchId = inserted.matchFK
   from inserted 
   inner join AT_LastViewedMatch on AT_LastViewedMatch.id=inserted.id

 
END
GO